# Cannot find Module when using npm install canvas

Tags: node.js

When i trying to write for a discord bot, i want to make the welcome image so i need the node-canvas. I have already installed the GTK2 and libjpeg-turbo-gcc but the terminal still report the "Cannot find Module" error

Command:

> npm install canvas

The Error:

> npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Surface Pro6\Desktop^^\node_modules\canvas

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936

npm ERR!   throw err;

npm ERR!   ^

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Surface

Pro6\Desktop^\node_modules@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp'

npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)

npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)

npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)

npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {

npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

npm ERR!   requireStack: []

npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!    C:\Users\Surface Pro6\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-11T11_39_03_707Z-debug-0.log

Comment: You should have white spaces in your directories name. That's what seems to cause the bug. Npm is looking for path `C:\Users\Surface` instead of `C:\Users\Surface Pro6`

Comment: I wrote you should instead of you shouldn't...   anyway goal seems to be reached :).